# How to set a subview's frame to be its parent's frame in a custom view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, subview

I want to set the custom view's frame as my subview's frame, which is a UILabel. but 
when I use self.frame the `UILabel` shows empty text. I need to hardcode the parameters in `CGRectMake` in order to see my `UILabel`. How do I set the UILabel's frame to be my custom view's frame?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withText:(NSString *)text
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        _text = text;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    // This works
    // UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40)];
    // This doesn't work
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    label.text = @"";
    if (![self.text isEqualToString:@"?"]) {
        label.text = self.text;
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }

    [self addSubview:label];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`layoutSubviews` will be invoked many times, so you should not `addSubview` like this. Better style is to set a property of UILabel, like your `text` property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel * label;
```

then change your `layoutSubviews` code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    if(!self.label){
         self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame]; //Use ARC
         self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
         [self addSubview:self.label];
    }

    self.label.frame = self.bounds;
    if (![self.text isEqualToString:@"?"]) {
        self.label.text = self.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. You do not want to create views inside the layoutSubviews method. It can be called multiple times, often in some cases, so you're taking a performance hit by checking if you've already created the label every time. And why set the initial frame to self.frame instead of self.bounds if you're going to then change it to bounds a few lines below? Also, setting the label.text property in this function is a bad idea. You don't control when this method will be called.

Comment: Of course! Put the init views in initWithFrame: is Ok. My code is a style of lazy load, put the init code where view begin to use will be better. Because  the code showed is limited , so I just put it in layoutSubviews. @Dave Wood

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 40)]; // set frame as you want
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; // set color as you want
label.text = @"Hellow";
[yourParentView addSubview:label];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withText:(NSString *)text
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        _text = text;

     [self layoutSubviews:frame];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews:(CGRect)myFrame
{
    // This works
    // UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40)];
    // This doesn't work
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
    label.text = @"";
    if (![self.text isEqualToString:@"?"]) {
        label.text = self.text;
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }

    [self addSubview:label];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to create views inside the `layoutSubviews` method. That method can be called multiple times and you'll create each view multiple times (having them overlap each other).

Instead create the views you need in the `initWithFrame` method.

For the answer to your actual question, you probably need to set the frame of the new label to the bounds of the custom view. The bounds will have an origin of 0,0 and so it will work no mater where the custom view is placed in it's superview. If you use the frame, the label will be offset by however much the custom view is offset.

You can probably completely remove your `layoutSubviews` method as that's not the place to set the label text either. Then add this:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withText:(NSString *)text
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (!self) return nil;

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    _text = text;

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    label.text = @"";
    if (![self.text isEqualToString:@"?"]) {
        label.text = self.text;
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }

    [self addSubview:label];

    return self;
}
```

If you want the label to resize when the custom view resizes, you could do that inside the layoutSubviews by setting the `label.frame = self.bounds;`, but you'd be better off using autoresizing masks or auto layout.